# How to check if multiple checkbox is selected or not in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DataGridview where I can select multiple checkbox.but now I need to collected checked rows data and keep it. how can I check how many of my rows are selected and how can I keep me selected checkbox rows data.

I already did little code. but this only keep only one selected rows data.
Here is my code:

```
DataGridViewCell datacelll = dgvSlsSRsList.CurrentCell;

if (datacelll != null)                   
{                           
    foreach (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell in dgvSlsSRsList.SelectedCells)
    {
        cell.Value = true;
        slssrsId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSlsSRsList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
        slssdpId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSlsSRsList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
        DueAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSlsSRsList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value);
    }
    dgvSlsSRsList.Refresh();                            
}
```

Comment: Why can't you loop through DataGridView ?

Comment: I would suggest you to bind your list as the Datatable.Datasource, then iterate on each row casting the "row.DataboundItem" in your model type. You'll then have just to check if your "rowObject" bool property is true.

Comment: I would go with @Leogiciel suggesting, bind a modelCollection to you gridView. 

And query your bound dataCollection with linq query to get the 'checked' data.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i get the solution from another post comment section.here is my solution-

```
                List<string> srlist = new List<string>();
                List<string> sdplist = new List<string>();
                List<string> dumamountlist = new List<string>();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvSlsSRsList.Rows)
                {
                    var cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value) == true)
                    {
                        srlist.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        sdplist.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                        dumamountlist.Add(row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());


                    }
                    else if (cell.State == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
                    {
                        srlist.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        sdplist.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                        dumamountlist.Add(row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                    }

                }
```